# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\prod\limits_{z^n=-1}(f(z)^n-1)}{\prod\limits_{z^n=1}(f(z)^n-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am trying to calculate the following limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\prod_{z^n=-1}(f(z)^n-1)}{\prod_{z^n=1}(f(z)^n-1)},$$ where $f$ is a holomorphic function of $z$ such that $|f(z)|<1$ for every $|z|=1$. I The same question for the case $|f(z)|>1$ for every $|z|=1$. I have no idea for solving this.

Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot!